# SVN revert on server side

Tags: svn, commit, revert

A ***very smart*** developer deleted almost an entire repository and committed it (rev 210). I have a working copy on my computer, but the repository is rather large.

I would like to create a new revision (211) that is identical to the last good revision (209). I don't want to keep anything from revision 210, which is the bad commit. It's the developers fault, and they will have to rewrite anything as far as I am concerned.

Ideas?

Comment: Deleting a file (or an entire repository) and then committing doesn't cause anything to be lost. That's the whole point of a version control system, it keeps you from permanently losing things if you make mistakes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If that developer didn't delete the repository on the server then *all your code is safe*. All you need to do to verify this is to create a new empty folder and then perform an SVN checkout from revision 209 instead of the HEAD. That will give you every single file in their state for revision 209. You can do this on any of your dev workstations, no need to do anything on the server.

To revert the changes, just pull up the SVN Show Log (if using TSVN) window in your working copy root and select revision 209, then select Revert to revision - this will do a reverse-merge of the changes in revision 210 which you can then check in as revision 211. That should solve your problem.

If the developer deleted the repository on your SVN server, you need a daily backup to restore your code.

As long as your repository on the server is intact it is not possible to delete anything from SVN. When you delete something, it simply becomes invisible from that point forward but you can always go back to any version of any file in the repository - you just need to go to the right revision.

Comment: Thank you. This solved the problem. Much appreciated.

I know the code is safe, I understand that part of SVN. I was just wanted to create a new revision (211) that was exactly like 209. Thanks so much!

Comment: @ScottCrooks I'm glad it helped. Would you mind accepting my answer in that case?

Comment: worked for me, but you have to checkout the head first, then revert to revision and so on...

Answer (score 7):

This can be solved by [reverse-merging](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn-book.html#svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.undo):

The following command will return your working copy to the state of revision 209:

```
svn merge -c -210 .
```

Then commit:

```
svn ci -m "reverse merged revision 210"
```

Answer (score 2):

There is one ugly way which works for me ... provided you want to delete the last commit and not some commit in the middle.

First - shutdown svn server and backup your repo by `svnadmin hotcopy repo repo_backup`

Go to the SVN server and proceed your repo. Look into ./db/revs/X/ where X is the first number of the wrong commit. You can see the wrong commit file there (e.g 123). Remove this file and then modify ./db/current to point to the commit before (e.g.122).

Comment: Works as charm !

Answer (score 1):

Modify the accepted answer a little in case you are using tortoise SVN

1. Update to the latest revision In this case Revision : 210
2. Open the repo logs
3. Select the revision that has to be the forced in this case : 209
4. Select Revert to this Revision
5. And then commit the changes as a new commit Revision: 211

Answer (score -1):

A rudimentary way on a Linux machine would be:

```
cp PRJ ../../bkup
svn up PRJ
cp ../../bkup PRJ
cd PRJ
svn add *
svn ci -m "everything again" PRJ
```

Hope you get the point